# How can a trigger perform a DDL statement without PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION?

Tags: oracle, triggers, transactions, pragma

To test some database pieces of a work project, I decided test it using triggers due to a nightly job.

The nightly job

1. Wipes everything from temporary tables
2. repopulates those tables from an outside database
3. merges the temp tables into primary tables
4. a couple other jobs

For the purposes of these tests I am not inclined to alter the source databases, but as the nightly job wipes the tables I cant just put values in which would work for my tests.

Due to the load processes, once they are finished a trigger is fired which alters the data in that table.

My problem is that I now want the triggers to perform a DDL statement (which commits) but also not have it PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION. The DDL statements either turn off the initial trigger (so it will only fire once) or activate the trigger that will clean up the test results the next time the nightly job runs (such as when triggered manually).

I do not want to make it PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION because in a different transaction means the nightly job and the triggers jobs wont see each other, and so the purpose of the tests cant be done, for example, adding a new employee, or a name change.

Comment: Simple answer: you can't

Comment: I don't understand from your description why you are using triggers at all. Why aren't you doing the triggered steps as part of the existing job? Or if you want some separation, as a chained jon?

Comment: @AlexPoole As this is testing I do not want to make any changes to the existing scripts. Yes, all the tests could easily be run by modifying the package. I just didnt want the package to be changed just to perform test cases. It feels wrong.

Comment: That's why I suggested [a chain](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/oracle-scheduler-concepts.html#GUID-FE177718-8A7E-4BDD-A8FC-1A41AF8A3517).

Comment: @AlexPoole I did not know about chains (so thank you very much for the link), they have been around since O10, so my dev of O11 and prod of O12 can make use of them. It will require some alterations but this might be able to do exactly what I need for the test cases (and might even improve the original package).

Comment: @AlexPoole Can you change your comment into an answer so that I can accept it please?