# DBMS_SCHEDULER Chain job not sending failed email

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, scheduler, chain

This is related to a past [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57400844/6891471).

This is being tested in 11 and 12, but eventually will only be in 12.

I have a package of just procedures. It was formerly made into a scheduled job by the job pointing to a single procedure which called the rest in sequence. It has now been converted into a chain job.

My chain job only ever sends out Success emails, when its set to send out both failed and success. When it was designed as the scheduled job, when it failed for any reason (there have been many) a failed email was sent.

For testing I developed the following case to fail

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM (
PROGRAM_NAME    => 'FAIL_1',
PROGRAM_TYPE    => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
PROGRAM_ACTION  => 'BEGIN
                    SELECT POSITION FROM DUAL;
                  END;',
ENABLED         => TRUE,
COMMENTS        => '');

DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP (
CHAIN_NAME      => 'HR_LOADER_CHAIN',
STEP_NAME       => 'F_1',
PROGRAM_NAME    => 'FAIL_1');

DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE (
CHAIN_NAME  => 'HR_LOADER_CHAIN',
CONDITION   => '"TRUE',
ACTION      => 'START "F_1"',
RULE_NAME   => 'FR_1',
COMMENTS    => 'FAIL RULE 1');  

DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE (
CHAIN_NAME  => 'HR_LOADER_CHAIN',
CONDITION   => '"F_1" FAILED',
ACTION      => 'END',
RULE_NAME   => 'FINISH2',
COMMENTS    => '');

DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE (
CHAIN_NAME  => 'HR_LOADER_CHAIN',
CONDITION   => '"F_1" STOPPED',
ACTION      => 'END',
RULE_NAME   => 'FINISH3',
COMMENTS    => '');
```

When the step fails, no email is sent and the chain just continues to run until I kill it. The log does show that the step was run and that it failed.

Here is the error message, so the program code will fail.

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
>   BEGIN
>                       SELECT POSITION FROM DUAL;
>                     END;
>   Error report -
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 28:
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "POSITION": invalid identifier
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 21:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

In case its important, here is how I am configuring the emails

```
Begin
    dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('email_server','Appmail.domain');
    dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('email_sender','my-application@email.domain');
End;

BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.add_job_email_notification (
        job_name    => 'my_CHAIN_JOB',
        recipients  => 'Fering@email.domain',
        events  => 'job_failed, job_succeeded' );
END;
```

The behavior seems to be that when my FAIL_1 program does its job (fails), that step of the chain is marked as failed in the run log, and then the chain just hangs. I actually have to run code to stop the chain.

I have tried having a Finish step with both failed and stopped conditions but neither respond to the event.

Update: Never did solve the chain email not working correctly. Requirements changed and we ended up going back to a regular scheduled job where the emails work as needed.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  You may need to invoke a procedure in the `DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN` PL/SQL package.

Comment: @MarkStewart testing was done in 11, but final servers will be 12, I will add it to the question

Comment: Approach for 11g and 12c for enabling emails are slightly different.  API for 11g is https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_networkacl_adm.htm#ARPLS67223 but a how to do this for 11g vs. 12c is in an APEX install guide that probably applies to your situation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMIG/enabling-network-services-in-Oracle-db11g-or-later.htm#HTMIG29161

Comment: @MarkStewart If emails are being sent for the success condition, why would they not send for the failed condition?

Comment: Sorry -- my bad.  I didn't notice that.  Did the scheduler job fail, or the job / script / PL/SQL invoked by the scheduler job fail?

Comment: @MarkStewart I have included some more details. The scheduler just hangs when there is succeed, failed, or stopped listeners that follow it.I have not tried completed for this.